# How to avoid reinstancing class instances returning from Redux on React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas, redux

### The problem

Currently, we are dissatisfied with our company's app performance and we want to enhance it by refactoring. I'm not going to go in detail on how it was but how we agree now it should be. The app has many moving parts and nested instances which all play a role in rendering what we are building, these instances are just pure js classes with relevant methods. One such example, from the older version is:

```js
export default class Gate {
  readonly id: string;
  name?: string;
  color?: string | null;
  xAxis: string;
  yAxis: string;
  parents: Gate[] = [];
  children: Gate[] = [];

  isPointInside(point: { x: number; y: number }): boolean {
     for (const parent of this.parents) {
       if (!parent.isPointInside(point)) {
         return false;
       }
     }
    return true;
  }
}

...

export default class PolygonGate extends Gate {
  points: { x: number, y: number }[] = [];

  isPointInside(point: { x: number; y: number }): boolean {
     return pointInsidePolygon(point, this.points) && 
            super.isPointInside(point);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the "isPointInside()" function takes a lot of care on how it's handled, and it depends on careful relation of class instances.

On our refactor, we want to rely as much as possible on React for managing state changes. That would mean we would use Redux for changes, basically any point in the app that calls a change can commit it. If I add a new Gate or change a gate's points, as explained in the example above, that would propagate down in the hierarchy from a top level component (Workspace) as props to others components which would render it.

```js
const Workspace = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const [workspace, setWorkspace] = React.useState(store.getState().workspace);

  useEffect(() => { setWorkspace(store.getState()) }, [store.getState])
  ...
}
```

This where the problem begins: we can't store class instances in Redux, therefore it would be plain JS objects.

### Proposed solutions

The first and easiest solution is to just re-instance every object received from Redux:

```js
const Workspace = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const [workspace, setWorkspace] = React.useState(store.getState().workspace);

  useEffect(() => { setWorkspace(store.getState()) }, [store.getState])
  ...
  const gates = workspace.gates.map(e => new Gate(e));
}
```

But this would mean every change would cause a huge number of objects to re-instanced. Needless to say, very expensive and we would have to manage links from one object to another.

Second option was to turn it all in purely functional components:

```js
// Instead of this
// gate.isPointInside(point)
// We would have this
isPointInside(gate, point)
// gate === pure js object
```

The comes with an associated host of problems. Firstly we would have to store everything on redux as references. For example, this could the structure:

```json
{  
  "plots": [
    {    
      // Plot data...
      "file": "a1b2c3-d4e5f6",
      "gates": [
        "010203-a4a5a6"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gates": [
     {
       // Gate data...
       "id": "010203-a4a5a6"
     }
  ],
  "files": [
    {
      // File data...
      "id": "a1b2c3-d4e5f6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which just sounds like a source of many potential problems caused by improperly managed dependencies between objects. Again, we would have to manage links from one object to another every single re-render.

Other solutions discussed was having an object pool which we could use, but that comes with it's own headaches and so on. Another option was to avoid Redux and self-implement a solution, but that sounds like like massive and buggy work, and would kinda defeat the purpose for the whole reason we considered Redux in the first place.

I would like to know from you, what do you think is the best approach here?

Comment: How did you measure that your original app's performance problems stem from how you are (were?) using classes?

Comment: Also, the proposed Redux solutions look very... non-Reduxy and downright buggy (though I could be mistaken). Why would you use local component state to "fork" the state that's stored in your Redux store?

Comment: The firs question: we didn't measure it, we just looked at it one day and realized how bad the performance was. We were updating a whole render structure on HTML5's canvas. Now we want a more permanent solution for that problem, which includes propagating changes down a tree of react components.

About the second question: most of our bugs were created from a component doing exactly what you described. We were considering redux precisely to allow global changes on state from anywhere in code without a bug ridden "fork" of state. Do you think that is the best approach? Pls tell me hehe

Comment: I don't know exactly what your app does (guessing it might have something to do with land use?), but did you consider e.g. overlaying multiple `canvas` elements as layers, and only updating those that need to be updated? Better yet, if SVG is a possibility, you can use React to reconcile a tree of SVG elements, so React will take care of only updating what's needed there and the browser will take care of updating only what's needed onto the screen...

Comment: We are implementing exactly that :) thanks a lot for validating our ideas. The question that this issue brings up is not related to rendering (because we are already implementing that solution) but how to manage the state of the things being rendered: how can we allow any part of the app to introduce changes to the global state and yet keep it tamed by dumping the data back into a top level component and let it trickle down all the way to the canvas overlays.

Comment: "How can we allow any part of the app to introduce changes to the global state and yet keep it tamed by dumping the data back into a top level component and let it trickle down all the way to the canvas overlays." If you're going with Redux, then by making the changes using Redux actions and selecting the data as desired with Redux's selectors in the components that need that particular data.

Comment: Yup, this is the thing that worries us: how to avoid having to reinstance the objects after we get them back from redux: should we go functional, use a "fork" of state instead of redux, literally just instance the object again, keep a pool of objects to use.

Comment: If you need cheap and trustworthy rerenders, I'd suggest going functional with a strict type regimen (since you're already using TypeScript anyway). Functional APIs are arguably easier to test too.